# Add array using array_push in multidemsional array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array of data which looks like this:-

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'amount' => 1.2,
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 0.53,
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 25.2,
    )
);
```

and another array

```
$n = array(
    'amount' => 12.98,
);
```

and then I use array_push

```
$p = array_push($a,$n);
print_r($p);
```

But the end result I get is

```
4
```

I want the array to be like :-

```
array(
    array(
        'amount' => 1.2,
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 0.53,
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 25.2,
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 12.98,
    )
);
```

What is thing which I am doing wrong? How can I fix it? Please help.

Comment: Open __please__ a manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_push` pushes the second argument onto the array specified in the first argument.  It returns the new number of elements, so:

```
array_push($a, $n);
print_r($a);
```

Or if you need a new array:

```
$p = array_merge($a, array($n));
print_r($p);

//or

$p = $a;
$p[] = $n;
print_r($p);
```

If a new array isn't needed, this is easier:

```
$a[] = $n;
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is normal as [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)'s 1st argument is *passed by reference* and:

> Returns the new number of elements in the array.

You just need to use it as:

```
array_push($a,$n);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($a, true) . '</pre>';
```

Or you could use the **array_push shorthand**:

```
$a[] = $n;
```

Comment: Of course it wasn't you, but I wonder why someone did it without any comment.

Comment: Before the edit is was the exact same as an existing answer, and that is not _short array syntax_ and has always been available in PHP.

Comment: You are right about short array syntax, corrected this. We were probably typing at the same time. If I was downvoting for similar answers posted after mine every time I'd be downvoting a lot.